# /etc/keystone/fernet-keys/ does not contain keys, use keystone-manage fernet_setup to create Fernet keys

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

I'm deploying openstack infrastructure - Victoria version with unbuntu pro 20.04 LTS. I run into the identity service - keystone in the controller node.

I follow the process explained in this [article](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/ussuri/install/keystone-install-ubuntu.html). I typed all cmds :

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "keystone-manage db_sync" keystone

keystone-manage fernet_setup --keystone-user XXXXXXXX --keystone-group XXXXXXXX

keystone-manage credential_setup --keystone-user XXXXXXXX --keystone-group XXXXXXXX
      
keystone-manage bootstrap --bootstrap-password YYYYYYYYY --bootstrap-admin-url http://controller:5000/v3/ --bootstrap-internal-url http://controller:5000/v3/ --bootstrap-public-url http://controller:5000/v3/ --bootstrap-region-id ZZZZZZZ
```

But, I cope with this error message :

```
/etc/keystone/fernet-keys/ does not contain keys, use keystone-manage fernet_setup to create Fernet keys.
```

Comment: Which command generates the error message? What's in `/etc/keystone/fernet_keys` before that command, and immediately after `fernet_setup`?

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but you follow Ussuri instructions to install Victoria, which might cause problems.

Comment: Thnaks. I finally solved the issue. I should proceed with the service name as identity.